# Woocommerce - Adding multiple products to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I'm using wordpress and woocommerce for my shop.

I'm using a plugin called Force Sells because I need to add a another product to the cart, when a specific product has been added.

I got multiple products and multiple Force Sells products.

Now I need to output/show the price of the product chosen for Force Sells on my product page. That means before checkout.
How do I do that?

If anyone has a more simple solution for this excluding the Force Sells plugin, I'm happy to hear about that too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about programming at all.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out myself.

I created a normal product for the force sells.

I added a custom field in Woocommerce as a dropdown.
The value of this dropdown was the ID of the product I just created.

Outputted the ID on product page in a price shortcode.

And thats it..